# TCP: Linux Kernel stops processing ACKs on my program's socket's behalf

Tags: linux, tcp, network-programming

I have a long running process listening on a TCP Socket and running under Linux. After several weeks of operation, it mysteriously stopped handling inbound connections. Upon investigation, I've found that for every connection, The remote end sends a SYN packet, to which my system responds with a SYN/ACK. The remote end then sends an ACK to complete the threeway handshake and tries to send data.

However my end never ACKs any of those data packets and instead keeps retransmitting the SYN/ACK, to which the remote end responds with a duplicate ACK, but my end again ignores it. Process repeats for a while and finally my side sends out a RST.

If not for the fact that the packet capture was taken on the same machine running my process, I would think that there was packet loss on the network and the remote ACKs were never received, the kernel is acting as if that were true, but clearly the ACKs are arriving as wireshark shows.

Other than acting like its not seeing the ACKs, the only other oddity I see in the wireshark (screenshot attached) is my outbound TCP packets have a wrong checksum, but I believe that's just due to the fact that I am taking the PCAP on that system and the checksum calculation is done later on.

Restarting the process made everything work normally again.

My question is what could cause this to happen, and what could I change in my program to prevent this from happening? It seems such a low level inside-the-kernel issue, I'm not sure what could be wrong in userspace to cause this

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

Comment: Could be a firewall that discards them in between the network driver (where wireshark sniffs) and the TCP stack?  Are you using iptables on that machine?

Comment: There are some iptable rules for icmp  but nothing for tcp. If it was a firewall issue though, I don't think restarting the process would get it working again, would it?

Comment: Another possibility is that your listening socket's accept queue is full

Comment: Thanks Ben. That looks like a likely candidate to cause this exact behavior: http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html

Comment: That information's old (it was already incorrect in 2014).  There is no queue of half-open connections, because that was a DoS vulnerability.  Today SYN cookies are used instead.  So the actually-open-but-not-accepted queue is the only one to worry about.

Comment: So the solution is to make sure you are calling `accept` in a timely fashion